# Изменить порядок вывода блоков с возможностью прокрутки

Tags: javascript, css

Я бы хотел узнать, как сделать, что бы этот блок прокручивался в браузере firefox. Я пробовал у родительского блока добавить `min-height: 0;`, не помогает. Заранее спасибо!

```css
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.parent div{
  width: 80%;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
  <div> 6 </div>
  <div> 7 </div>
  <div> 8 </div>
  <div> 9 </div>
  <div> 10 </div>
  <div> 11 </div>
  <div> 12 </div>
  <div> 13 </div>
  <div> 14 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').scrollTo(0, 999999999);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.viewport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.viewport div {
  width: 80%;
  background: #aaa;
}

.viewport div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
    <div> 4 </div>
    <div> 5 </div>
    <div> 6 </div>
    <div> 7 </div>
    <div> 8 </div>
    <div> 9 </div>
    <div> 10 </div>
    <div> 11 </div>
    <div> 12 </div>
    <div> 13 </div>
    <div> 14 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня проблема в том, что нужно начинать прокручивать блок снизу, как в чатах или сообщениях

Comment: @Stas, тогда немного js добавте (обновил ответ).

Comment: спасибо, я так понял, решения с чистого css без проблем с поддержкой браузеров нет?)

Comment: @Stas, теоретически можно попробовать заморочиться с `transform: rotate(180deg)`. Но замучаетесь...

Comment: да, я так пробовал, мучения больше, чем 1 строчка js кода